# como retorna array pata html via ajax/php

Tags: php, html, ajax

eu tenho a função abaixo no arquivos functions.php

```
function get_ADRESS(){
    if(isset($_POST['getcep']) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){   
        $cep = escape($_POST['cep']); //10   
        $cep = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $cep);
        $url = "http://viacep.com.br/ws/$cep/xml/";
        $xml = @simplexml_load_file($url);
        echo $xml;
    }
}
```

}

`$XML` é uma matriz que me retorna cep, rua, uf, número. O que eu preciso eh rodar a funcao get_endereco na página register.php e depois informar esses valores no HTML abaixo, como consigo fazer isso ?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-10">           
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Endereço" id="cep_load" name="cep_load" value="{$cep}">
    </div>
 </div>  


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-10">           
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Endereço" id="address" name="address" value="{$rua}">
    </div>
 </div>  
 <div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-lg-10">

     <input class="form-control" id="city" name="city"  placeholder="Cidade" value="{$cidade}" >
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos ter 1 arquivo chamado getAdressAjax.php

```
<?php
require 'function.php';
get_ADRESS();
?>
```

*(vou supor que seu projeto usa JQuery) [**(segue exemplo)](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) Neste caso a requisição só é chamada quando o usuário tira o focus do campo 'cep_load'.

```
$('#cep_load').blur(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "getAdressAjax.php", success: function(result){
        $('#address').val(result.endereco);
        $('#city').val(result.cidade);
    });
});
```

[Caso use Javascript puro apenas segue exemplos](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_examples.asp)

Buscando "ajax example" no google você já acha muita coisa BOA.

Comment: Bartomeu, Muito obrigado msm! Abs